# Why in Windows 2008R2 hkey_users sub keys does not match user profiles count?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop-services, windows-registry, user-profile

I'm trying to set default proxy setting for all users (including remote desktop users) via the registry ( under `HKEY_USERS\<USER_SID>\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\`)

On a classical server or workstation each user have a profile and a corresponding registry entry under HKEY_USERS  .
But in windows 2008R2 I have noticed that users who log in using only remote desktop does not have a subkey under HKEY_USERS :
take a look at the image bellow : 31 profiles found under %systemdrive%\users, but only a few keys are found in HKU 
[image]

So I wonder where are the internet explorer settings store here ?

Comment: Mandatory profile on that server ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 if mandatory is the opposite of roaming profile : yes

Comment: no, well, mandatory is a userprofile on the server, that all other is based on when a user connect. user setting are flushed at loggoff

Comment: I can't answer this, how to verify?

Comment: Check there, it explain how to do it; http://www.jasonsamuel.com/2012/12/10/how-to-create-a-windows-7-or-server-2008-r2-mandatory-profile-for-appsense/ It would be local GPO, and a ntuser.dat renamed to 'ntuser.man' in one profile

Comment: Why would you push out a GPO to the HKEY_USERS registry and not via GPO as a user policy to apply on logon ?

Comment: I'm not authorised to create/push gpo

Comment: @yagmoth555 thanks for the link, not sure if this is what I am after...seems a bit over complicated ....

Comment: @Kayasax I told that point only to answer why you can have 31 folder, while only two in hkey_user :)

Comment: @yagmoth555 in fact this answers my question. Please write an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use mandatory profile on that server the difference between HKEY_USERS and the numbers of profile on the disk can be explained.

What is a mandatory profile ? this is quote from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?)

> A mandatory user profile is a special type of pre-configured roaming user profile that administrators can use to specify settings for users. With mandatory user profiles, a user can modify his or her desktop, but the changes are not saved when the user logs off. The next time the user logs on, the mandatory user profile created by the administrator is downloaded. There are two types of mandatory profiles: normal mandatory profiles and super-mandatory profiles.

See there a simple [link](http://www.jasonsamuel.com/2012/12/10/how-to-create-a-windows-7-or-server-2008-r2-mandatory-profile-for-appsense/) that explain how mandatory are done;